# How to create a user account and add some of the data conditionally based on values user selects - Node JS

Tags: node.js, mongodb, rest

In my Node JS API, user creates an account, user can be a driver or a normal user. Drivers have to add their cars to the database but the users don't. I made an if else, if the user is not a driver, we save their data to the database else if he is driver, he needs to enter more data.

So I wanted to ask what should I put in the else condition, to make user enter data and get data in backend from request.

Should I make a separate API for adding car and make the front end call two different APIs on different buttons, one for User account and one for car data or is there any better method?

Here is my API code

```
exports.signup = async (req, res) => {
  const isUserExists = await User.find({
    $or: [{ Email: req.body.email }, { PhoneNumber: req.body.phoneNumber }],
  }).exec();

  if (isUserExists.length >= 1) {
    return res.status(400).json({
      message: "User Already exists",
    });
  } else {
    const newUser = await new User({
      _id: new moongose.Types.ObjectId(),
      FirstName: req.body.firstName,
      LastName: req.body.lastName,
      Email: req.body.email,
      PhoneNumber: req.body.phoneNumber,
      Cnic: req.body.cnic,
      Role: req.body.role,
    });
    role = req.body.role
    if (!role) {
      const result = await newUser.save();
      if (result) {
        res.status(201).json({
          message: "Account successfully created!",
        });
      } else {
        res.status(500).json({
          message: "Error creating an account!",
          error: err,
        });
      }
    } else {
      //I have to Get car data here
    }
  }
};
```

Comment: Hello Abdullah! I would say keep it all in the initial request: On the font-end, let the user enter the car information if he's a driver. You could for example add a checkbox to ask if he's a driver, and if so, give the user a few more input fields related to the car stuff.  Otherwise you would need two requests as you said, which would result in unnecessary traffic.

Comment: Thank you @EricQvarnström. I will work on that.